# What software is used to add animated characters to live TV?

Tags: animation, live

Specifically, I am wondering how Cartoon Donald Trump was added, voiced, and puppet-ed in clips such as

Comment: My guess is that this was done as a pre-recorded spot, with trump animated and added in post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they added this in post with a program like after effects(but this is simple enough that they could have even used a video editor). The cartoon was made in a program like after effects, blender, or any other animation program.